# veil framework, reverse https and tcp payload differences

Tags: metasploit, python

I am using veil framework to bypass av, when i want to choose a payload there are many choices, there is:

- `rev_https_contained`
- `python/meterpreter/rev_https`
- `c/meterpreter/rev_tcp`

My question is what is the difference between first two shell codes, and is there any advantages to use https payloads?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple benefits using https:

- More likely that firewalls will accept this traffic, rather than a random port.
- HTTPS encryption hides what is beeing sent over the network, so IDS/IPS systems will not see what is going on - given that there is no SSL termination (transparent).
- HTTPS will look more normal in firewall logs. It is not unexpected as connections to random ports.